# How do I attach CSS styles to all the pages?

Tags: 8

i have a theme installed his name is 'businessplus_lite' i want to add some custom style to my sub theme , but i can't see any css applicable , can anyone help me please !

> .info.yml

```
name: mysub-theme
type: theme
description: 'my sub-theme Commissions'
core: 8.x
base theme: businessplus_lite

libraries:
  - my-sub-theme-name/my-sub-theme-style
```

> libraries.yml

```
my-sub-theme-style:
  css:
    component:
      css/components/style.css: {}
```

Comment: Change `component` to `theme` and maybe add a `version`. Simply try to do it exactly the same as it's described in the docs: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme

Comment: it doesn't work bro :(

Comment: And of course you have activated the theme, set it as default and flushed cached at least twice, before checking a page in that theme via browser, right?

Comment: yeah of course bro , i have have doing all that

Comment: I'm not your bro. But good to know. Better add these information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using below code
**info.yml :**

```
name: mysub-theme
type: theme
description: 'my sub-theme Commissions'
core: 8.x
base theme: businessplus_lite

libraries:
  - mysub-theme/my-sub-theme-style
```

**mysub-theme.libraries.yml :**

```
my-sub-theme-style:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/style.css: {}
```

Comment: it doesn't work bro :(